# reduce is not a function at Object.sum

Tags: javascript

I have this example of code

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3]
let summableNum = Object.assign({}, numbers, {
  sum: function() {
    return this.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + b
    })
  }
})
```

the result is:

```
{
  "0": 1,
  "1": 2,
  "2": 3,
  sum: f
}

summableNum[0]  // 1
```

when i execute summableNum.sum(), i have this error

> Uncaught TypeError: this.reduce is not a function
>       at Object.sum (:4:17)
>       at :11:17

expected result:

```
summableNum.sum() // 6
```

can you help me

Comment: why an object for the items?

Comment: Its an object, not an array. objects don't have reduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `summableNum` is the `{}` object, which doesn't have a `.reduce` property. Use an array instead:

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];
const summableNum = Object.assign([], numbers, {
  sum() {
    return this.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  }
});
```

Or use a copy of the array:

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];
const summableNum = Object.assign(Array.from(numbers), {
  sum() {
    return this.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Either assign a `sum` property to the actual array instance, or to `Array.prototype` (generally not recommended, since it mutates a built-in prototype - it's usually not a good idea to mutate objects you don't own):

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3]

// Method 1:
const summableNum1 = [...numbers];
summableNum1.sum = function() {
  return this.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b
  })
};

console.log(summableNum1.sum());

// Method 2:
Array.prototype.sum = function() {
  return this.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b
  })
};
const summableNum2 = [...numbers];
console.log(summableNum2.sum());
```

A different option is to create a class that `extends Array` which has the `sum` method:

```js
// Method 3
class SummableArray extends Array {
  sum() {
    return this.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  }
}
const numbers = new SummableArray(1, 2, 3);
console.log(numbers.sum());
```

Answer (score 1):

if you only want `nums` to have a method `sum`, then I would avoid attaching it to the prototype... and [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) is more appropriate then `Object.assign` for this job.

```js
const nums = [1, 2, 3];

Object.defineProperty(nums, 'sum', {
  value: () => nums.reduce((a, b) => a + b),
});

console.log('[1,2,3].sum() =', nums.sum())
```

---

However, the right way to go (in my opinion), is to be more functional...
If you separate the data from its behaviour, the reusing code becomes much easier:

```js
const sum = nums => nums.reduce((a, b) => a + b);

console.log(sum([1, 2, 3]));

// but also sum([55,56,57]) and so on
```